AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'fit_generator'
**This is my current code :
**
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Convolution2D
    from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
    from keras.layers import Dense
    from keras.layers import Flatten

    classifier = Sequential()

    classifier.add(Convolution2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape=(64, 64, 3), activation='relu'))

    classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=2))

    classifier.add(Flatten())

    classifier.add(Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))

    classifier.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))

    classifier.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

    batch_size = 32

    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
            rescale=1./255,
            shear_range=0.2,
            zoom_range=0.2,
            horizontal_flip=True
            )

    test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

    train_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
            'dataset/training_set',
            target_size=(64, 64),
            batch_size=batch_size,
            class_mode='binary'
        )

    test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
            'dataset/test_set',
            target_size=(64, 64),
            batch_size=batch_size,
            class_mode='binary'
        )

    classifier.fit_generator(
            train_set,
            steps_per_epoch=8000 // batch_size,
            epochs=20,
            validation_data=test_set,
            validation_steps=2000 // batch_size
        )

**When I am trying to compile it, here is the generated error image :
**
File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
exec(code, globals, locals)
File c:\users\91831\desktop\ai\dl & nn\cnn\cnn.py:50
classifier.fit_generator(
AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'fit_generator'
**I am running on CPU on spyder. I have also installed tf, keras. But when I try to compile, I am getting above error. Can I replace fit_generator by fit? Or is there any alternative solution?**

Model.fit_generator is deprecated since tensorflow 2.1.0
you could fix it by using Model.fit to use ImageDataGenerator as input
ref: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model
